# After Execution How to Write Request and Response in external file in Postman client ?

Tags: export, response, postman

I am exploring postman client, but I didn’t get any option to export request and respective response after excitation. 
So that we can it as Proof of Testing and share it with client as well.

Scenario is:

1)  Create few request (Get/Post/Put)
2)  Execute all request at a time or one by one 
3)  Once execution is completed we should get request and its response in e external file for each request

There is option available to export Request and response separately

Please suggest if any option is available with respect to my response

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check these blog post's by the PostMan team:

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/

You will still need to copy them to a text file, but this will allow you to save them in the current context and then copy them at a later time when all the requests have run through.

Or you can try to run the same through a command line script, which will allow you to save the file via redirection.